# Next.js vercel puppeteer 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, puppeteer, vercel

I'm using puppeteer to take screenshots of websites on the /api side of next.js:

```
"use server"
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda')


export async function POST(req, res) {
    console.log(req.method)
    const search = new URLSearchParams(req.url)
    const { protocol, host } = req.headers;
    const fullUrl = `${protocol}://${host}${req.url}`;
    const newURL = new URL(fullUrl);
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(newURL.search);



    const url = searchParams.get('url');
    const browser = puppeteer.launch({headless: 'new'})

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    const buffer = await page.screenshot({ type: 'png' });
    await browser.close();

    console.log(buffer)

    const base64Image = buffer.toString('base64');

    return NextResponse.json({image: base64Image})

}
```

This works fine on my computer, but I get errors on vercel:

```
⨯ Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 119.0.6045.105). This can occur if either
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/sbx_user1051/.cache/puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
    at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (file:///var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:260:27)
    at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (file:///var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:197:25)
    at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (file:///var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:91:37)
    at async ChromeLauncher.launch (file:///var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:53:28)
    at async POST (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/img/route.js:1:1304)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:14:39523
```

I tried to use `puppeteer-core` instead, but I get another error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (174:32)
|                 private: true,
|                 access: {
>                     has: (obj)=>#applyViewport in obj,
|                     get: (obj)=>obj.#applyViewport
|                 },
```

I also tried:`const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda')` insead of normal puppeteer. The only difference is that:

```
 const browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
        args: [...chromium.args, "--hide-scrollbars", "--disable-web-security"],
        defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
        executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
        headless: true,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      })
```

And I got the error:

```
./node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/build/puppeteer/lib/Browser.js.map
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> {"version":3,"file":"Browser.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../../../source/puppeteer/lib/Browser.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":";;AAGA,IAAI,KAAK,GAAuB,IAAI,CAAC;AAErC,IAAI;IACF,KAAK,GAAG,OAAO,CAAC,4CAA4C,CAAC,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC;CACvE;AAAC,OAAO,KAAK,EAAE;IACd,KAAK,GAAG,OAAO,CAAC,iDAAiD,CAAC,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC;CAC5E;AAED,KAAK,CAAC,SAAS,CAAC,WAAW,GAAG,KAAK,WAAW,GAAG,KAAa;IAC5D,IAAI,IAAI,GAAS,IAAI,CAAC;IACtB,IAAI,KAAK,GAAW,MAAM,IAAI,CAAC,KAAK,EAAE,CAAC;IAEvC,IAAI,KAAK,CAAC,MAAM,KAAK,CAAC,EAAE;QACtB,KAAK,GAAG,CAAC,MAAM,IAAI,CAAC,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC,CAAC;KAChC;IAED,IAAI,GAAG,KAAK,CAAC,KAAK,EAAE,CAAC;IAErB,IAAI,KAAK,IAAI,IAAI,IAAI,KAAK,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC,KAAK,CAAC,KAAK,IAAI,EAAE;QAClD,KAAK,IAAI,IAAI,IAAI,KAAK,EAAE;YACtB,IAAI,GAAG,MAAM,IAAI,CAAC,IAAI,CAAC,CAAC;SACzB;KACF;IAED,OAAO,IAAI,CAAC;AACd,CAAC,CAAC;AAEF,IAAI,OAAO,GAAQ,KAAK,CAAC,SAAS,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC;AAE3C,KAAK,CAAC,SAAS,CAAC,OAAO,GAAG,KAAK,WAAW,GAAG,KAAa;IACxD,IAAI,IAAI,GAAS,MAAM,OAAO,CAAC,KAAK,CAAC,IAAI,EAAE,SAAS,CAAC,CAAC;IAEtD,IAAI,KAAK,IAAI,IAAI,IAAI,KAAK,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC,KAAK,CAAC,KAAK,IAAI,EAAE;QAClD,KAAK,IAAI,IAAI,IAAI,KAAK,EAAE;YACtB,IAAI,GAAG,MAAM,IAAI,CAAC,IAAI,CAAC,CAAC;SACzB;KACF;IAED,OAAO,IAAI,CAAC;AACd,CAAC,CAAC"}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? What's the simplest/most effective solution? Thank you so much!

Comment: From what i remember you need to have chrome or chromium installed on machine. When Puppeteer want for example to take screenshot, in reality it will launch a "virtual" instance of chrome, without GUI. I was only able to deploy such script via docker and download script that make it work, but not in Vercel.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm experiencing the same

Comment: I didn't find a solution. I tried getting puppeteer-core instead but then there were a ton of issues with compatibility and nothing ever properly ran ;-;